# Can I compare a variable set by auth_request_set after the auth_request has returned in nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I've got a location block with an `auth_request` like this

```
location /somepath {
    auth_request /authorize;
    auth_request_set $header_variable $upstream_http_custom_header;

    proxy_path http://backendaddress;
}
```

What I want to do is, if the `$header_variable` doesn't match a particular regex I want to return a 403 code.

`if` isn't going to work because it runs too early.  Is there anything else that would let me do this?

Comment: Is it something like pre-validation? Why **if** conditional expression is to early? Is so, one more location with *rewrite* and condition there may help... You intend to check the header before make *auth_request*, correct?

Comment: if happens in the rewrite phase, I want to check the value of the variable *after* `auth_request` returns

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this? I've been testing and no matter where I put my `if{}` it won't have the variable set by `auth_request_set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx module [auth_request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) waits for either 200 or 401/403 HTTP code from the backend:

> The ngx_http_auth_request_module module (1.5.4+) implements client
>   authorization based on the result of a subrequest. If the subrequest
>   returns a 2xx response code, the access is allowed. If it returns 401
>   or 403, the access is denied with the corresponding error code. Any
>   other response code returned by the subrequest is considered an error.

Your request has a header that require to check for permission:

> What I want to do is, if the $header_variable doesn't match a
>   particular regex I want to return a 403 code.

During auth request/response cycle your backend needs to check the header and return 403 code to prevent next request to happen without authentication. The module *auth_request* works as a simple test assert which returns one of the code. It does mean backend process that is responsible for this URL to reply http://backendaddress/authorize needs to have an additional check for required header.