# Nginx is not handling auth_request before if statement

Tags: nginx, configuration, nginx-reverse-proxy

It's probably easiest to just show by example where I'm hitting issues, so I'll jump right in...

This snippet will work as-is for Nginx with rewrite/auth modules enabled. So hopefully this issue is quick & easy reproduce on pretty much any Nginx install...

```
server {
  listen 8081;
  add_header x-user bar;
  return 200;
}

server {
  listen 8080;

  location = /auth {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
  }

  location / {
    auth_request /auth;
    auth_request_set $foo $upstream_http_x_user;

    add_header x-test $foo;
    add_header success true;

    proxy_pass http://example.com/;
  }
}
```

The above example Nginx site config does the following:

1. Sends any request to `/auth` via an `auth_request`  call
2. The /auth location sends the request to another server which adds a header `x-user bar`
3. `auth_request_set` sets a new var `$foo` based on the upstream header value of `x-user` set in step 2 above.
4. A new header is set `x-test` which is set to the value of `$foo`
5. The request proceededs to an external destination.

**Response is exactly how I would expect, and confirmed the `$foo` var was set correctly:**

```
$ curl -s --head http://localhost:8080 | grep -E 'HTTP|x-test'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-test: bar
```

So, here comes the problem... 
**I need to adjust this config so that it'll return 403 if the value of the upstream header is incorrect.**

Seemed like a simple task. So I added an `if{}` conditional to check the header:

```
  location / {
    auth_request /auth;
    auth_request_set $foo $upstream_http_x_user;

    # this 'if' is the only part added to the original config
    if ($foo != bar) {
      return 403;
    }

    add_header x-test $foo;
    add_header success true;

    proxy_pass http://example.com/;
  }
```

The `if` conditional evaluated true so I got a 403, which is not what I was expecting. **So, this does not work**:

```
$ curl -s --head http://localhost:8080 | grep -E 'HTTP|x-test'
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

I realize that [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) however I seem to be using it just to **return** which should be ok. I'm open to using any method to accomplish the same goal - with or without **if**, so I'm open to ideas!!

I have tried doing things like moving the `auth_request` and/or the `if` statements into the `server{}` block but nothing seems to make this evaluate the way I was expecting.

---

### Further Troubleshooting / Details:

**I have verified the problem is that the `if` is evaluated BEFORE the `auth_request_set` is**

```
  location / {
    auth_request /auth;
    auth_request_set $foo $upstream_http_x_user;

    if ($foo != bar) {
      # x-test never gets set because $foo is null when if evaluates
      add_header x-test $foo always;
      add_header success false always;
      return 403;
    }

    add_header x-test $foo;
    add_header success true;

    proxy_pass http://example.com/;
  }
```

```
$ curl -s --head http://localhost:8080 | grep -E 'HTTP|x-test|success'
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
success: false
```

---

**I have verified this is not an issue if using `set` instead of `auth_request_set`**. This works (but doesn't accomplish the goal):

```
  # set works, but not auth_request_set
  location / {
    set $foo bar;

    if ($foo != bar) {
      return 403;
    }

    add_header x-test $foo;
    add_header success true;

    proxy_pass http://example.com/;
  }
```

**This config works. `set` is evaluated before `if`:**

```
$ curl -s --head http://localhost:8080 | grep -E 'HTTP|x-test'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-test: bar
```

---

**The behavior persists even if the `auth_request` is in the `server{}` context**:

```
server {
  listen 8081;
  add_header x-user bar;
  return 200;
}

server {
  listen 8080;

  auth_request /auth;
  auth_request_set $foo $upstream_http_x_user;

  location = /auth {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
  }

  location / {

    if ($foo != bar) {
      return 403;
    }

    add_header x-test $foo;
    add_header success true;

    proxy_pass http://example.com/;
  }

}
```

```
$ curl -s --head http://localhost:8080 | grep -E 'HTTP|x-test|success'
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
success: false
```

I've reviewed the following docs and questions:

- [Can I compare a variable set by auth_request_set after the auth_request has returned in nginx?](https://serverfault.com/questions/713560/can-i-compare-a-variable-set-by-auth-request-set-after-the-auth-request-has-retu)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73431103/cant-access-added-headers-using-nginx-auth-request-set
- [Nginx $upsteam_cache_status custom header will not appear](https://serverfault.com/questions/954333/nginx-upsteam-cache-status-custom-header-will-not-appear)
- [auth_request doesn't block return directive, can't return status?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1057520/auth-request-doesnt-block-return-directive-cant-return-status?rq=1)
- https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if
- https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/

Comment: Is there a reason that you cannot put the `auth_request` in the `server` context?

Comment: I've tried that and it has the same behavior. I've tried both `auth_request` and `auth_request_set` in server context, and a mix with only `auth_request` in server and `auth_request_set` in location. All return 403 every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` is a problematic, because it is an imperative construct in otherwise declarative configuration.

Therefore it doesn't always work as expected. More information can be found in [IfIsEvil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) article.

In this case, the `set` and `auth_request_set` happen in different stages of nginx request processing, and the `if` processing happens between those two stages.

Unfortunately I don't know how to actually do what you want in nginx. Maybe that needs to be done in the upstream server where you proxy the request to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if you have any outside the box ideas, please let me know!! The upstream server has a 1:many relationship with a bunch of these nginx listeners in question, and each one has a different "valid" value for the var being checked, so I would really like to avoid moving that config to the upstream. I'm still hammering at it. I was thinking of some sort of `map` to replace the `if` but can't seem to work out viable logic for that.

Comment: This is technically the correct answer to my question. You simply cannot do it with `if`. My specific issue/scenario/use-case isn't necessarily solved, but the question itself is answered.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question, [see Tero's answer here](https://serverfault.com/a/1121907/583269) for the actual answer (spoiler: `if` is ***truly*** evil, even if using it with `return`).

However, as a functional answer providing a workaround: Here is at least a way to make invalidated requests get sent a 403. The proxy_pass endpoint is dynamic depending on the tested header. This seems to solve the use-case...

```
upstream barhost {
  server example.com;
}


map $foo $choose_upstream {
  default 127.0.0.1:8999;

  # cannot use hostnames here since they don't resolve. Using an upstream instead. 
  bar barhost;
}

server {
  listen 8999;
  return 403;
}

server {
  listen 8081;
  add_header x-user bar;
  return 200;
}

server {
  listen 8080;

  auth_request /auth;

  location = /auth {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
  }

  location / {
    auth_request_set $foo $upstream_http_x_user;
    proxy_set_header Host example.com;
    proxy_pass http://$choose_upstream/;
  }
}
```